# \mathscript{F} yields undefined control sequence error

Tags: math-mode

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 for compiling my TeX documents. I am getting an error with contains the line `$\mathscript{F}$` showing that it is undefined control sequence. How should I rectify it?

Comment: did you see any documentation that suggested `\mathscript` should work? what package did that documentation suggest?

Comment: See table 299 in the current edition of the [“Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List”](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) or look for `\mathscr`.

Answer (score 5):

You're perhaps after `$\mathscr{F}$` from the `mathrsfs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{F}$
\end{document}
```